C# GraphQL StrawberryShake Init problems
I am trying to initialize a new graphQL client in Visual Studio 2022 using the StrawberryShake.Tools command:
dotnet graphql init {Endpoint} 

However it always fails with an error

Error HTTP_ERROR: Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed)

After a little research and getting little help from the GraphQL server developer, I am running under the assumption that the server simply does not allow this operation and so I cannot use the tool to initialize the client.
If anyone has any information on how I might actually get this tool to work I would love to know. I believe that the GraphQL endpoint requires a bearer token. I also have tried using the --scheme Bearer {Token} option and it returns the same result.
Since It seems I cannot actually use the tool to init the client, I set out to attempt to manually set up the schema and the graphqlrc.json file to see if it will still work.
I was able to pull the Schema text from the server using a manual query provided to me by the developers that built the application.
I added the schema.graphql file and the graphqlrc.json file from a template I found online.
After installing the nuget packages and a query.graphql file, I tried various things to get it to auto generate the C# code with a build.
Things I have tried include:

Make sure the .graphql file is in the root of the project.
Modify the build action on the file properties to GraphQL Compile.

No matter what I try, it does not produce any generated code.
I am wondering if there is something I am missing in the process, or is there some other modification that is made when the dotnet graphql init command is run that I am missing in my manual setup.
Does anyone have any ideas for me to try?
I previously described the things I have tried.
The endpoint is wi-fiber.sonar.software/graphiql This is an instance of the cloud application sonar.software which is a cloud CRM IPAM and Inventory Management system aimed at WISPs and FISPs. Here is a link to their documentation of how to consume their API. docs.sonar.expert/system/consuming-the-sonar-api The documentation confirms that it is served by HTTPS and uses only the POST verb.

Did you ever figure this out? I also am trying to add the token or authorization bearer token but cannot figure it out. I get forbidden 403 error if I do without.

I eventually ended up talking to one of the application developers who explained that I was using the wrong endpoint. I was using the address of the graphiql web app where you can manually run queries and the endpoint is different.  I still am not clear if this is common practice, but it was the simple answer.
I did get stuck for a minute after correcting the endpoint because it kept giving me an unauthorized 401 response. I was using the --token flag to send my Auth token for the init. The documentation indicates that the default token scheme is Bearer, but I did have to specify it with the --scheme Bearer flag. Once I added that, it went through without any issue.

I eventually ended up talking to one of the application developers who explained that I was using the wrong endpoint. -- then might you please [edit] your answer to share the correct endpoint?  As well as flags mentioned in the second paragraph required to make it work.  As it is, your answer isn't really usable by anyone other than yourself.  Thanks!
